# Error on Run Execution through IDE Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, filenotfoundexception

I've tryied to execute a class file Java, through Eclipse IDE, but it has returned this error:
"It is impossile to search the main class file.java caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : file.java"

I've setted the environment configuration, added the variable path through settings Run Configurations, but it has seemed not enough because the class has not belonged to be searched.
What's the matter caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException and how can solve it ?
Thank you
Best Regards

Comment: ".java" is part of the source file's name, not the class' name (which is the value without the filename extension, and declared in the source itself).

Answer (score 0):

Ok  so it's wrong to name main class with extension .java but I have to set the name of  main class correctly. I've obtained also this message of error: "Error: it's impossible to search or to load the main class:  file". The detail of the error log is the following-"System property https.proxyPort is set to 8080 but should not be set." This has been obtained in virtual system of work.
While at the local system I've obtained this message: "An internal error occurred during: "Launching New_configuration (1)"." with its exception stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.jdt.launching.IVMInstall.getLibraryLocations()" because "install" is null
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.AbstractJavaLaunchConfigurationDelegate.getBootpathExt(AbstractJavaLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.AbstractJavaLaunchConfigurationDelegate.getVMSpecificAttributesMap(AbstractJavaLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaLaunchDelegate.getVMRunnerConfiguration(JavaLaunchDelegate.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaLaunchDelegate.launch(JavaLaunchDelegate.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1021)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$2.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1224)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)"`
```

[image]

Comment: is that meant to be an *answer*, or continuation of the question?

Comment: This is a question obsiouvsly but I know I have to focus better the matter. This is the trace of log. If you can help me I thank you if you can't help me no problem.